# How can I start go server permanently?

Tags: ssh, go, nas

I've got problem with my Go server.

When I'm connected to my NAS via SSH and do `./gogs web`, the server is starting. But when I close the SSH connection, the server is stopped.

How I can start my Go server permanently?

Comment: Did you try typing `./gogs web &` to send the server into the background? This is not a Go-specific question; it's just how UNIX works.

Comment: `nohup ./gogs web &` will detach it from your current session when you logout

Comment: Hi Adrian, what is your NAS and the OS it hosts ?

Comment: My NAS is a QNAP TS-112

Answer (score 1):

You have scripts in gogs allowing you to launch the server as a daemon:

- [`scripts/init/debian/gogs`](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/blob/f03b6be8f997efbcfea45326629e532e834b998b/scripts/init/debian/gogs) (recently fixed with [issue 519](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/pull/519))
- [`scripts/init/centos/gogs`](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/blob/cd084dacf1108e483461f8c99a0771ce3b402dc4/scripts/init/centos/gogs)

That would allow the process to remain while the session is closed.

You have other options in [issues 172](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/172).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Go-specifioc problem, what is happening is that the Go program is still attached to your terminal and when you log out, the kernel will trigger a SIGHUP to every binary still connected to that terminal session.

Your best option is probably to use `nohup ./gogs web`.

Second-best option would be to rewrite main, so that it intercepts and handles SIGHUP, stopping it from killing your program. However, doing so requires handling quite a few things properly (you really should close stdin, stdout and stderr; make sure all your logging is done through the log library, ...)